# How to map data from tsv file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, csv

i have function which converts tsv file to json however i wanted to make key value pair in json output. tsvJSON function returns the json but i want to format in certain structure.

tsv.file

```
Row ID  O ID    O Date  Ship Date   Ship Type   Customer ID Customer Name   Seg Country City    State   Zip Code    Region  Product ID  Category    Sub-Category    Product Name    Sales   Quantity    Discount    Profit
1   PA-152156   11/9/20 01/19/16    Second Class    CG-125  Clay bute   Consumer    United States   Henderson   Kentucky    42420   South   FUR-BO-10001798 Furniture   Bookcases   Bush, Somerset Collection Bookcase? 261.96  2   0   41.9136
```

main.js

```
  const tsvFileData = fs.readFileSync('./filename1.tsv');
    const jsonRes = tsvJSON(tsvFileData.toString());
    const fs = require('fs');
    function tsvJSON(tsv){

      var lines=tsv.split("\n");

      var result = [];

      var headers=lines[0].split("\t");

      for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

          var obj = {};
          var currentline=lines[i].split("\t");

          for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
              obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
          }

          result.push(obj);

      }

      return result; //JSON
    }
```

returning this

```
[
    {
        "Row ID  O ID    O Date  Ship Date   Ship Type   Customer ID Customer Name   Seg Country City    State   Zip Code    Region  Product ID  Category    Sub-Category    Product Name    Sales   Quantity    Discount    Profit": "1   PA-152156   11/9/20 01/19/16    Second Class    CG-125  Clay bute   Consumer    United States   Henderson   Kentucky    42420   South   FUR-BO-10001798 Furniture   Bookcases   Bush, Somerset Collection Bookcase? 261.96  2   0   41.9136"
    }]
```

expected output

```
[{
    "Row ID": 1,  "O ID":"PA-152156","O Date":"11/9/20"  , "Ship Date": "01/19/16", and rest of the fields mapping 
}]
```

Comment: pattern "\t" will not work for your tsv file . See here https://www.regextester.com/?fam=115953

Comment: @Supercool what would be correct way to achieve this can share an example ?

Comment: i tried split(/\s\s/) it was doing something near to expected result

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your tsv file is not well formated so the total of headers doesn't return as expected...

Let's suppose this file was separated by 'semicolon', the following example will work...

filename1.tsv

```
ID;NAME;PHONE_NUMBER
1;WILLIAN;(11)98550-3485
```

main.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

const splitBy = ';'

function tsvJSON(tsv){

    var lines=tsv.split("\n");

    var result = [];

    var headers=lines[0].split(splitBy);

    for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

        var obj = {};
        var currentline=lines[i].split(splitBy);

        for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
            obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }

        result.push(obj);

    }

    return result; //JSON
}

const tsvFileData = fs.readFileSync('./filename1.tsv');
const jsonRes = tsvJSON(tsvFileData.toString());
console.log(jsonRes)
```